# Swig wrapper for variable argument lengths

Tags: python, c, swig, word-wrap

I am trying to wrap the method below with swig and I seem to be having some trouble with the way argc and agrv values are being passed into the rtserver.c method below from server.py.

```
int initialize(int run, int argc,char *argv[]) {
```

This is the part of rtserver.i that should handle the data.

```
%include <argcargv.i>

%apply (int ARGC, char **ARGV) { (int argc, char *argv[]) }
```

In the server.py file that implements the wrapped rtserver methods I try to take the argument passed in from the command line and then send it to the wrapped message.

```
c = sys.argv[1:]
sock = rtserver.initialize(0,c)
```

As can be seen from the output of the server.py file when run. It seems like the string array is being correctly read into the server.py file. The error seems to show up when the array is passed to rsterver.initialize(). There the string array is garbled from what I've been able to figure out none of the arguments can be parsed and instead the system is started with the stored default values.

```
python server.py -rp 41104 -ep 41000 -tp 10011
['-rp', '41104', '-ep', '41000', '-tp', '10011']

Fri May  1 22:57:11 2015: 7429 : rtserver :Started (version 1.6) listening on port 41103 for control program, and on port 1024 for clients
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or maybe just a way I can actually get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation it turns out that the argument loading argv inside the initialize method was incorrect.

If other people are running into a similiar problem where it doesn't seem like swig is correctly wrapping argc and argv you can change the typemap to the following to allow you to see if your arguments are being passed correctly. Hopefully, it will help you trace down the true source of the error.

```
%typemap(in) (int argc, char *argv[]) {
      int i = 0;
      if (!PyList_Check($input)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Expecting a list");
        return NULL;
      }
      $1 = PyList_Size($input);
      $2 = (char **) malloc(($1+1)*sizeof(char *));
      for (i = 0; i < $1; i++) {
        PyObject *s = PyList_GetItem($input,i);
        if (!PyString_Check(s)) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "List items must be strings");
            return NULL;
        }
        $2[i] = PyString_AsString(s);
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n",i,$2[i]);
      }
      $2[i] = 0;
}

%typemap(freearg) (int argc, char *argv[]) {
       free($2); 
}
```